# Drill down line chart where two line meet at a point in HighChart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

Need to drill down the line chart.
But when two lines are meeting at the same point.One of the line is hidden at that point. I am not able to drill down the hidden line . Please suggest any method other than the deselecting the  line chart in legend list.

Comment: code or didn't happen

Comment: Okay, but what do you expect to do? You have two points, one under another: always one of points will be unreachable?